# Sort structures in file

Tags: vim, emacs, sorting

For example I have file consisting of structures like

```
name = {
   foo = bar;
   ...
};
```

So in file there are lots of structures like this.
How can I sort them (I'm using `vim` but `emacs` is surely ok too) by name? But having their fields unmodified?
I mean

```
b = {
   bfoo = bar;
   ...
};
a = {
   afoo = bar;
   ...
};
```

Goes to

```
a = {
   afoo = bar;
   ...
};
b = {
   bfoo = bar;
   ...
};
```

**Update**
Structures may also contain same structures.

```
b = {
   c = {
       cfoo = bar;
       ...
   };
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following would work with vim. Perhaps easier to wrap into a function.

```
:%s/$/$
:g/= {/.,/};/join!
:sort
:%s/\$/\r/g
```

In a nutshell

```
1. Replace the EOL with a special character (I've chosen $)
2. Search for "= {" and join all lines up until first "};"
3. Sort 
4. Replace the special EOL character back to a real EOL character.
```

Comment: Please, check an update.

Comment: @JagJaga - if the indentation of the root element is fixed, you can alter the search to something like `:g/\v^\w \= \{/.,/\v^\};/;/join!`. The `\v` sets very magic so you can use `^` in a search to indicate the start of a line *(but now you have to escape the =, { and } characters)*

Answer (score 0):

For Emacs, use function `sort-regexp-fields` - see the Elisp manual, node [`Sorting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html#Sorting).

You can also use function `sort-subr`, which is even more general, or function `sort-paragraphs` or `sort-pages`.  For the latter two, the sections to be sorted would need to be separated by one or more blank lines (for paragraphs) or form-feed (`^L`) characters, and there would need to be no such characters within any section.